# Object turning infinitely on custom physics simulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, physics-engine, verlet-integration

[Video Link](https://streamable.com/3wih8z)

I have custom physics simulation that uses verlet. And I have a car made from nodes and joints. It turns constantly when car turn up down. There is damping and friction force.

Here is my collision response:

```
private void ApplyCollisionResponse(Vector3 contact_point,Vector3 contact_force)
{
    foreach (Deformable deformable in Deformables)
    {
        foreach (Node node in deformable.Nodes)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(node.transform.position, contact_point) < 1f)
            {
                //node.transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(node.transform.position,node.transform.position+contact_force,5f*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                
                float velocity = Vector3.Dot(contact_force, node.GetVelocity());
                Vector3 current_projection = velocity*contact_force.normalized;
                Vector3 diff = (- current_projection);
                Vector3 impulse = Vector3.Lerp(current_projection,diff*node.GetMass(),0.5f);
                node.AddForce(impulse);

                // Move the node slightly along the collision force direction
                Vector3 collision_fix = 1.01f * contact_force   ;
                node.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(node.transform.position, node.transform.position +  collision_fix, 0.5f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my node code:

```
private Vector3 GetForce()
{
    Vector3 totalForce = Vector3.zero;

    // Additional forces (e.g., user input, springs, etc.)
    totalForce += AdditionalForces;
    // Drag force
    totalForce += -0.05f * Velocity.magnitude * Velocity.normalized * GetMass();

    AdditionalForces = Vector3.zero;

    return totalForce;
}

public void UpdateVerletIntegration()
{
    Velocity = (transform.position - prevPosition) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Velocity *= (1-Damping);

    Vector3 force = GetForce();
    Vector3 gravity_force = Physics.gravity * Mass;

    if (force.magnitude < 0.001f)
    {
        force = Vector3.zero;
        Velocity = Vector3.zero;
        transform.position = prevPosition;  
    }

    Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + Velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime + ((force+gravity_force) / Mass) * Mathf.Pow(Time.fixedDeltaTime, 2);
    prevPosition = transform.position;
    transform.position = newPosition;
    // Verlet 
}
```

I want to solve this turning problem.

Comment: The problem is that despite being called "Verlet", this is not the (mathematical) Verlet method. Usually the slowing down is achieved by the constraint correction in the collision code that does something uncontrollably wrong, but has effects that look not too bad. Thus it could be that you did something wrong, or that you did everything right, but this false-physics-by-collision does not influence the rotation. // Note that magnitude times normalized vector equals the original vector. // Could the 3 friction sources counteract each other?

Comment: I have tried many options that can slow or damping the problem. But Collision response always accumulating and turns the node group. What do you mean as 3 friction sources? @LutzLehmann

Comment: You have a friction term in the force. Then the coefficient in the Verlet formula. And the effect of the constraint enforcement. That last one is hard to bring into a form that can be physically interpreted. Did you try what happens if you reduce the step size? Reduce it by a factor of 10 and do 10 integration steps per frame?

Comment: Nearly nothing changed. It continuesly turns. I think everyting properly implemented. 
Its like natural behaviour of the code. Using this joint type can cause problem in verlet? firstly I tried euler physics. But it was very unstable and hard to control. Verlet one is very stable for joint except this problem. Am I trying a wrong usage? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Mechanics with constraints gives an index-3 DAE system (differential-algebraic equations, the "algebraic" ones are the derivative-free constraints // the index tells how often one needs to differentiate the constraints until a pure ODE system results). The projection method, restore the constraints after each integration step, works for index-1 systems, perhaps still for index-2.

Comment: For higher index it is almost guaranteed that hidden constraints, here the energy and momentum evolution, are violated. This can have unpredictable consequences, like, apparently, here that the angular momentum and speed evolves opposite to the correct physical behavior.